# Making a fetch call within a nested for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, lambda

I'm currently converting my local function into a lambda function and am running into a few hardships. In a previous method, I get an array of url fragments that I have to string along programmatically to a prefix to get the data back.

Logically, I figure the best way of doing this is to do a nested for loop. Go through the series of prefixes adding the url fragment and doing the fetch call.

It works fine in local, but lambda throws errors.

```
function getVariantData(data, cb) {
  for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
    let source = chapters[i];
// chapters = url prefix
    data.forEach(async element => {
      let res = await fetch(chapters[i] + element);
//element = url fragment
      let body = await res.text();
      createVariantsFile(element, source, body, cb);
    });
  }
}
```

this code runs fine but i've learned that lambdas are a bit more strict with forEach and async/awaits so I've changed my code to this and I've been dealing with a mess of issues. I havent gone past writing console.log because...well I haven't gotten past the error.

```
async function getVariantData(data, cb) {
  for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
    let source = chapters[i];
    const promises = data.map((datum, index) => fetch(source+datum))
    const chapterData = await Promise.all(promises)
    console.log(chapterData)
    // await data.map(async element => {
    //   return await (chapters[i] + element);
    //  createVariantsFile(element, source, body, cb);
    // });
  }
}
```

Comment: The question would be easier to understand if you didn't change variable names between the two versions, e.g. `element -> datum`.

Comment: The first version is using `.text()`, the second version is not.

Comment: What error is the second version throwing?

Comment: ah sorry about that, i re-edited variable names because i experimented with new functions to get arround it

the second version is throwing a time out error:

{
  "errorMessage": "2020-03-09T19:31:13.454Z f601e3b9-2a19-459d-a7a6-58000fd6e72a Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Comment: You're probably sending too many AJAX requests at once to the same server. There's a limit on the number of concurrent requests, so the rest are being queued up, and then you're getting a timeout on them.